# Linq agrupa e buscar o max id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, webforms

Existe alguma forma de otimizar o código abaixo de forma que faça a busca dos formulários que esteja com a máxima versão de acordo com o `IdCentroCusto`?

No código abaixo estou fazendo o agrupamento e pegando o `CM.Max(d => d.Versao)` para buscar o o eu formulário correto.

```
var Formularios = qrFormularios
                       .GroupBy(F => new { F.IdCentroCusto, F.Versao })
                       .Select(CM => new
                       {
                           Formulario = qrFormularios.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Versao == CM.Max(d => d.Versao) && n.IdCentroCusto == CM.Key.IdCentroCusto),
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

Precisaria de uma query que me retornasse todos os campos do formulário.

```
[Serializable, Table("tb_Formularios")]
    public partial class rtb_Formularios 
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 IdFormulario { get; set; }
        public Int32 IdModFormulario { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public String TituloFormulario { get; set; }
        public Int32 Vigencia { get; set; }
        public Int32 IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public Int32 IdCentroCusto { get; set; }
        public Int32 Versao { get; set; }
        public Int32? IdLogStatus { get; set; }
        public Int32 IdPassoWorkflow { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DtTransmisao { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtInclusao { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public Byte[] SeqAlteracao { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Int32 PKValue
        {
            get { return IdFormulario; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marconcilio, você pode primeira fazer uma subquery para retornar a Versão mais recente de cada centro de custo... depois você faz um join com esta subquery.

```
var centrosCusto = 
    from formulario in qrFormularios
    group formulario.Versao by formulario.IdCentroCusto into grupo
    select new { 
        IdCentroCusto = grupo.Key, 
        Versao = grupo.Max(versao => versao)
    };

var formularios = (
    from formulario in qrFormularios
    join centroCusto in centrosCusto on new { formulario.IdCentroCusto, formulario.Versao } equals new { centroCusto.IdCentroCusto, centroCusto.Versao }
    select formulario;
).ToList();
```

Comment: perfeito vlw...